# How to remove a row if the difference between two columns is less than 2000

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    69091   70008   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000186092.4"; transcript_id "ENSG00000186092.4"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "OR4F5"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "OR4F5"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001094.1";
chr1    ENSEMBL gene    134901  139379  .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000237683.5"; transcript_id "ENSG00000237683.5"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "AL627309.1"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "AL627309.1"; level 3;
chr1    HAVANA  gene    367640  368634  .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000235249.1"; transcript_id "ENSG00000235249.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "OR4F29"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "OR4F29"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000002860.1";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    621059  622053  .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000185097.2"; transcript_id "ENSG00000185097.2"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "OR4F16"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "OR4F16"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000002581.1";
chr1    ENSEMBL gene    738532  739137  .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000269831.1"; transcript_id "ENSG00000269831.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "NOVEL"; gene_name "AL669831.1"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "NOVEL"; transcript_name "AL669831.1"; level 3;
```

I'd like to remove genes where the difference between $5 and $4 is less than 2000 using awk if it's possible. Though sed is acceptable as well.

So it returns the following:

```
 chr1   ENSEMBL gene    134901  139379  .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000237683.5"; transcript_id "ENSG00000237683.5"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "AL627309.1"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "AL627309.1"; level 3;
```

Thank you.

Comment: column 5 is always larger?

Comment: Yes column 5 is always larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk '$5-$4 >= 2000' file`

if $5 always larger than $4